# Problems installing Hadoop on Windows 7 Enterprise N

Tags: maven, hadoop, installation, kerberos

Currently I’m trying to install Hadoop 2.6.0 on a Windows 7 enterprise computer.
I used the following guide 
http://www.srccodes.com/p/article/38/build-install-configure-run-apache-hadoop-2.2.0-microsoft-windows-os

I already fixed some previous problems by installing a correct version of Protocol Buffer.
But now ran into a new problem.

```
> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal
> org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.2:exec (compile-ms-winutils) on
> project hadoop-common: Command execution failed. Process exited with
> an error: 1(Exit value: 1) -> [Help 1]
```

I searched the internet and found that perhaps my MSBuild was causing the problem, but I check my PATH and it contained the MSBuild path to the correct location. I’m using  .Net Framework 4.0

I tried running “mvn clean install” and from the tests I got the following errors.

```
> ------------------------------------------------------------------------------- Test set:
> org.apache.hadoop.security.authentication.client.TestKerberosAuthenticator
> ------------------------------------------------------------------------------- Tests run: 14, Failures: 0, Errors: 2, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 33.35
> sec <<< FAILURE! - in
> org.apache.hadoop.security.authentication.client.TestKerberosAuthenticator
> testAuthenticationHttpClientPost[0](org.apache.hadoop.security.authentication.client.TestKerberosAuthenticator)
> Time elapsed: 2.201 sec  <<< ERROR!
> org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException: null
>                 at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryExecute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:693)
>                 at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:520)
>                 at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:906)
>                 at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:805)
>                 at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:784)
>                 at org.apache.hadoop.security.authentication.client.AuthenticatorTestCase.doHttpClientRequest(AuthenticatorTestCase.java:265)
>                 at org.apache.hadoop.security.authentication.client.AuthenticatorTestCase._testAuthenticationHttpClient(AuthenticatorTestCase.java:291)
>                 at org.apache.hadoop.security.authentication.client.TestKerberosAuthenticator$4.call(TestKerberosAuthenticator.java:160)
>                 at org.apache.hadoop.security.authentication.client.TestKerberosAuthenticator$4.call(TestKerberosAuthenticator.java:157)
>                 at org.apache.hadoop.security.authentication.KerberosTestUtils$1.run(KerberosTestUtils.java:102)
>                 at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>                 at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
>                 at org.apache.hadoop.security.authentication.KerberosTestUtils.doAs(KerberosTestUtils.java:99)
>                 at org.apache.hadoop.security.authentication.KerberosTestUtils.doAsClient(KerberosTestUtils.java:115)
>                 at org.apache.hadoop.security.authentication.client.TestKerberosAuthenticator.testAuthenticationHttpClientPost(TestKerberosAuthenticator.java:157)
> 
> testAuthenticationHttpClientPost[1](org.apache.hadoop.security.authentication.client.TestKerberosAuthenticator)
> Time elapsed: 1.914 sec  <<< ERROR!
> org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException: null
>                 at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryExecute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:693)
>                 at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:520)
>                 at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:906)
>                 at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:805)
>                 at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:784)
>                 at org.apache.hadoop.security.authentication.client.AuthenticatorTestCase.doHttpClientRequest(AuthenticatorTestCase.java:265)
>                 at org.apache.hadoop.security.authentication.client.AuthenticatorTestCase._testAuthenticationHttpClient(AuthenticatorTestCase.java:291)
>                 at org.apache.hadoop.security.authentication.client.TestKerberosAuthenticator$4.call(TestKerberosAuthenticator.java:160)
>                 at org.apache.hadoop.security.authentication.client.TestKerberosAuthenticator$4.call(TestKerberosAuthenticator.java:157)
>                 at org.apache.hadoop.security.authentication.KerberosTestUtils$1.run(KerberosTestUtils.java:102)
>                 at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>                 at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
>                 at org.apache.hadoop.security.authentication.KerberosTestUtils.doAs(KerberosTestUtils.java:99)
>                 at org.apache.hadoop.security.authentication.KerberosTestUtils.doAsClient(KerberosTestUtils.java:115)
>                 at org.apache.hadoop.security.authentication.client.TestKerberosAuthenticator.testAuthenticationHttpClientPost(TestKerberosAuthenticator.java:157)
```

I again try to find information about this error on the internet but I could not find a solution.

Do you have any idea what I might be missing or how I could solve this error?

Many thanks.

Daniel

Answer (score 0):

When I tried building with Win7 I had to remove the double ** in the .java file comment sections.  Don't know why, but for some reason maven did not like these.  Example, check for this in DefaultRequestDirector.java near line 693.  If line 693 appears to be inside a comment, then that is the problem. Just change the ** to * at the start of the comment.